# Stored procedure - SELECT INTO Variable

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures

I was wondering why I can't get this to work inside a stored procedure.

The logic goes like this:

```
SELECT table.column, table.column, ..., case (when SELECT table.column ..., when, ...)
FROM ... WHERE ...;
```

works fine. But if I want to store the case result into a local variable like this:

```
DECLARE TEMP_VAR ...;

SELECT table.column, table.column, ..., TEMP_VAR = case (when SELECT table.column ..., when, ...)
FROM ... WHERE ...;
```

it throws unexpected token "="..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select statement use in two case.
One is Retrieve value and second is assign value.

But your case shuold be retrieve value and assign value. That is not possible.

Comment: Thank you. Figured it was something like this. D;